# Where best to handle async calls when consuming remote REST APIs

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, synchronous

I'd like to hear various design considerations around an iOS client consuming back-end API/services. Specifically, where in the client is it best to leave the asynchronous thread management?

The approach I'd taken until now is to have an API wrapper class handle all requests synchronously, and then have the calling class handle the asynchronous thread management. My primary objective in handling interactions with the back-end in an asynchronous nature is to smooth the user experience (vs parallel handling for performance, etc.).

So with this approach, we have the API wrapper class:

```
@implementation APIWrapper

- (NSDictionary *)getRecord (NSNumber *)recordId {
  NSDictionary *record = nil;
  NSString *url = @"http://myhost/api/records";
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
  NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
  if (responseData != nil) {
    record = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
  }
  return record;
}

@end
```

and the consuming class handling the asynchronous thread management (we'll throw the records into a UITableView:

```
...
  self.recordsQ = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  ...
  NSDictionary *record = nil;
  [self.recordsQ addOperationWithBlock:^{
    record = [self.apiWrapper getRecord:recordId];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    if (record != nil) {
      [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        cell.textLabel.text = record objectForKey:@"name";
      }];
    }
  }];
  ...
  return cell;
}
```

The other approach seems to be use `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest]` with a `completionHandler` block, which I haven't used myself.

What are the advantages/disadvantages/considerations between the two uses?

Also, I'm generally open to comments/improvements to the current synch method I've been employing as well.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should use `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest]`. You might also want to consider using a framework such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), which already provides nice classes to wrap requests in NSOperations.